# Dynamics AX: Filter out ItemGroup on Custom Form Lookup

Tags: axapta

On the form InventItemIdLookupPurchase, I need to display all Item Groups except Service.

Can I achieve this without writing a custom lookup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do need a [custom lookup](http://www.axaptapedia.com/index.php?title=SysTableLookup_class).